# Linux user security

Tags: linux, security

When a user is created in Linux, their username can be seen publicly in the `passwd` file. Is there a hash set for that?

Comment: Er, yes, the user name is visible publicly. You can pick a pseudonym if you like, but the name has to be unique, and will be visible to the other users. I have no idea what “is there a hash set for that” means.

Comment: Did that actually answer your question? It seemed like your main question was "Is there a hash set for that?", but I don't know what that means

Comment: If you don't want users visible you can use another user database, accessible from nsswitch. Perhaps LDAP, or database.

Comment: Well, you should probably explain what you're asking then, since we're a bit confused

Comment: Please don't reply to comments, unless you have information to add. But please do what the comments request. Your questions are really not clear, and you will not get good answers, because people don't understand your questions. I recommend that you read [how to ask questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the links on the right as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes, the user name is visible publicly. You can pick a pseudonym if you like, but the name has to be unique, and will be visible to the other users

In addition to what [@gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) has already stated. The primary key, unique identifier of a user is the `uid` which is the 3rd field in the password file, or in the below example the *'1000`*

```
xenoterracide:x:1000:100::/home/xenoterracide:/bin/zsh
```

to create another user that's effectively the same you could add

```
bob:x:1000:100::/home/xenoterracide:/bin/zsh
```

which has the same `uid` therefore is the same user. So unix uses an integer (or is it a short) to denote the actual `user id`. No hashes are needed outside of the users password.

The password is hashed, but what type of hash is defined by pam configuration, in my case I'm using sha512.

```
password required        pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok
```

Comment: @ xenoterracide- Thanks so much.BTW,There is one man who knows my question.